# CSS Reset script interfering with 1 link

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which can be seen in the link below:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/V88c6/8/show/

Here is the full jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/V88c6/8/

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="head_1">
    <div class="inner">

        <div class="column_0">
            LOGO
        </div>

        <div class="column_1">
            <a href="#" class="menu_link">LINK 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu_link">LINK 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu_link">LINK 3</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu_link">LINK 4</a>
        </div>

        <div class="column_2">
            <span>USER NAME</span> <a href="#" class="menu_link">LOGOUT</a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the LOGOUT link's top border on hover seems to be a pixel higher then the rest of the links.  This happened when I added some [css reset script](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/).

Here is a link of the same page without the css reset where the LOGOUT link works fine:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/V88c6/9/show/

I like to use the css reset script to help the page look similar on most popular browsers.

Anyone know why the css reset script would be interfering with the LOGOUT link only?

*Tested on IE7, IE8, Latest Google Chrome, latest Firefox, Latest Opera.*

Comment: I dont understand why you make such an easy menu in such a hard way. Why dont you use a `ul` `li` system?

Comment: It's actually 2px. Reduce the `padding-top` by 2px to 15px to fix. Not sure why it's happening though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to style it the bad way. Try styling it like this - whit **li ul**:

```
<div class="column_1">

 <ul class="menu_link">
 <li><a href="#" >LINK 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" >LINK 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" >LINK 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" >LINK 4</a></li>
 <ul>

</div>

<div class="column_2">

 <ul class="menu_link">
 <li>username</li>
 <li><a href="#" >LINK 4</a></li>
 <ul>

</div>
```

and these are the selectors:

```
.menu_link li{}
.menu_link li a{}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OP's HTML choice, just a different approach.  The real issue stems from understanding CSS's visual formatting model for inline elements versus block elements.  The OP's mark-up is a bit simpler, and that has some merits.

Comment: @MarcAudet if that were true, why have different HTML tags at all, and not just put everything in `<x>` tags? A collection of links in a container is by all means an *unordered list*, and as such should be in a `<ul>` element. From a purists point of view the columns themselves should also be `<li>` elements when we get to the semantic nitpicking (but then I'd also starting b*tching about using layout terms like `clearfix` as class names, breaking semantics and the pure HTML/CSS separation inherently, and numbering classes).

Comment: @Niels You do raise a good point about semantics.  I very often use an unordered list for menus.  Occasionally, though, I just through a bunch of `<a>` tags in a `<div>`, float and style and job done!  Keep in mind, it is good to be able to deal with both approaches since you may have to style/skin a CMS template (WordPress...) where you are given HTML and refactoring is not an option.

Comment: @Niels, any chance you could show me an example of my html/css done properly without breaking semantic guidelines/rules?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one also

```
#head_1 .inner .column_2 {
display: block;
float: right;
padding: 0 15px;
}

#head_1 .inner .column_2 .menu_link {
border-top: 17px solid transparent;
padding: 17px 15px 10px 15px;
display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the computed value for the `display` property.

Your middle column with "LINK 1" and so on shows `.menu-link` with `float: left`, which causes the `<a>` elements to be block instead of inline.

You "LOGOUT" link shows `.menu-link` with no float, so the `<a>` element is inline.

The inline element affects the height of its inline box differently from a block element.

There was some style property in your browser's default style sheet that was masking this effect, and when you used a reset CSS style sheet, it appears.

The fix would be to layout out the two elements on the right (User Name and Logout) as floated element or to tweak the margin or line height by 1-2 px (involves trial and error, groaning).

**The Fix**
I was able to get a consistent layout by doing the following by adjusting your CSS as follows:

```
#head_1 .inner .column_2 {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    /* padding:34px 0px 10px 15px; Remove this... */    
}

#head_1 .inner .column_2 .menu_link{
    border-top:17px solid transparent;
    padding:17px 15px 10px 15px;    
    float: left; /* add this.. */
}

/* Float your span like you floated the link... */
#head_1 .inner .column_2 span {
    border-top:17px solid transparent;
    padding:17px 15px 10px 15px;    
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Myhcy/

The key is to keep a consistent coding style in laying out your two menus.

Comment: I'd prefer not to do the 1-2px tweak fix, and would prefer to structure it correctly so it works correctly.  I'll give this a go now.  Thanks.

Comment: Your jsfiddle still seems to give me the same problem as my original problem?  I just tested it on IE7, IE8, Chrome, FireFox, and Opera.

Comment: @oshirowanen I forgot to click the "Update" and "Set To Base" buttons in my fiddle.  Please take a second look.  Thanks!